# Super key ("The Windows Key") not working in i3wm in 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, i3-wm

I just installed i3wm but I can't configure the $mod to be mod4 (<kbd>Super</kbd> aka "the Windows Key" in other OSes). I can only choose to use the mod1 (<kbd>Alt</kbd>).

I've tried reinstalling i3, and deleting the configure file to create a new one, without any good results. I really want to use <kbd>Super</kbd> because using <kbd>Alt</kbd> often conflicts with other program's short cuts.

Anyone else had this problem or have any suggestions on how I can fix this. I've used i3wm before with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS without any problems whatsoever.

Comment: Which repository did you use for installation of i3?

Comment: Ubuntu's by "sur5r". (https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html). 

I did the following in the terminal when I installed it: 
echo "deb http://debian.sur5r.net/i3/ $(lsb_release -c -s) universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list apt-get update
apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install sur5r-keyring
apt-get update
apt-get install i3

Answer (score 8):

Run `xev` and whenever you press the super key you should see something like this:

```
KeyPress event ...
    root 0x25, subw 0x0, ...
    state 0x0, keycode 89 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    ...
```

If this doesn't work I can't help you. If it does then just note the description of the key just after the keysym. It's `Super_L` in this example but it might be something else in your case. Now execute these commands:

```
xmodmap -e "clear mod4"
xmodmap -e "add Mod4 = Super_L"
```

***ATTENTION:** make sure you replace `Super_L` with the description that `xev` prints to you in the above commands *

The curious can also run `xmodmap -pm|grep mod4` in the end which should show `mod4    Super_L`

Comment: Any idea on how how to *translate* this answer to *setxkbmap*?

Comment: Sorry Knight - no idea.

Comment: Thanks for the original answer, anyway. I made a [new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388512/super-key-a-k-a-windows-key-not-working-in-i3wm-fedora-26)  that might bring an answer.

Answer (score 6):

If `xev` isn't displaying anything when you press the key, make sure your keyboard isn't in a "gaming mode". I ran into this with a Logitech G710+. The button to toggle the mode looks like a little joystick and apparently one thing it does is disable the "Windows key". I assume it's to keep you from being pulled out of a full screen game if you miss pressing `CTRL` or `ALT`.

Comment: Same issue with my Logitech G610 Orion in Debian 10.1. Switching out of game mode (which had been on by default) allowed for it to register in `xev`.

Comment: You are a life saver, I was pulling my hair about this problem

Answer (score 5):

I've got this issue on Ubuntu 18.04, where apparently my device has `Fn + Super` mapped to disable the super key. During this state, the Super key didn't work, and I couldn't switch to any of my tags (I'm using dwm). However, presing `Fn + Super` to toggle out made everything work again.

Comment: This answer is gold!

Comment: OMG, never thought about such state existence... nothing helps, and this is just laptop feature!! thank you